# auto-remove of files from U1 account as soon removed from U1 folder

Tags: ubuntu-one

I have some personal photos and I doesn't like to disclose it to anyone. But I need a copy of each of them in U1. So, I put all of them in the U1 folder and they were uploaded to my U1 account. Then I removed all of them from the folder. Because, someone may see them when they open the U1 folder. I believed that copies of these photos reside in the U1 account. So, I logged in to U1 website via browser to view them. But I couldn't see any of them there(account was synced with my folder!). But i have a backup copy of these. So, I didn't lose them. Now, I need a copy in U1 account of these photos. But it should not be removed from the U1 account as soon as i removed from the U1 folder. So, can you help me to solve the problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ubuntu One (U1) is a file and folder synchronization service. It is designed to keep the files in our computers in sync with the files in the cloud. It is not designed to be a file storage and backup system. So if you delete the files from your local folder they will be deleted from the U1 server and any other computers you have U1 signed on with the same account.

To do what you want, remove the computer (Remove Device) from Ubuntu One's account. You can do this by going to the Ubuntu One web page, signing in, and going to the "My Account."

Then Ubuntu One will not sync files from this computer. You can still upload the photos and other files in Ubuntu One using the web interface.

However, if you have other computers, phones etc. associated with this Ubuntu One account, the photos and files will be downloaded in those devices.

Hope this helps.