# Dont delete files on server when we delete ours?

Tags: ubuntu-one, files, sync, delete

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [auto-remove of files from U1 account as soon removed from U1 folder](https://askubuntu.com/questions/186290/auto-remove-of-files-from-u1-account-as-soon-removed-from-u1-folder)

Currently, when I create a file (in a folder sync with ubuntu one), it uploads it on its server.
Then what I want is "when i delete this file on my PC, it wont delete from the server"

indeed I use Ubuntu one for two reason :
1/ If my PC burns, I can recovery them
2/ If someone come and delete my precious files, I can recovery them.

Is there a way ?

thanks sorry for my english im french :)

Answer (score 1):

Ubuntu One is a file and folder synchronization service. It is designed to keep the files in our computers **in sync** with the files in the cloud and your 9 other computers (assuming you have 10 computers).

It is not designed to be a file storage and backup system. So if you delete the files from your local folder they will be deleted from the Ubuntu One server and any other computers you have Ubuntu One signed on with the same account.

See [auto-remove of files from U1 account as soon removed from U1 folder](https://askubuntu.com/questions/186290/auto-remove-of-files-from-u1-account-as-soon-removed-from-u1-folder).